# Simple-looking problem with integrals

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, convexity

Let $f: [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(0) = 0$. Is it true
that if the integral
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(\theta) f(\lambda \sin(\theta)) \, d\theta
$$
is zero for every $\lambda > 0$, then $f$ is identically zero?

It's rather obviously true if $f$ is a polynomial and I'm hoping it is true in general, which is perhaps why I'm stuck.

**Edit.** I came across this problem in two different, but related contexts. I'll describe the easier one: given a positive continuous function $F : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the functions $\kappa_\lambda(\theta) := F(\lambda\cos(\theta))$, with $\lambda > 0$, are all curvature functions of plane ovals evaluated at the point of the curve where $(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$ is the normal vector if and only if
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-i\theta} \kappa_\lambda(\theta) \, d\theta = 
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-i\theta} F(\lambda\cos(\theta)) \, d\theta = 0
$$
for all $\lambda > 0$. If $F$ is even, this is always the case, but does it have to be even? Well, after you decompose $F$ into even and odd parts and play around with this you come to the problem posed above and so nicely solved by Fedor Petrov and Mateusz Kw'asnicki below. Their solution readily implies that

A continuous function $F : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is even if and only if
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-i\theta} F(\lambda\cos(\theta)) \, d\theta = 0
$$
for all $\lambda > 0$. In other words, all the ovals will be centrally symmetric.

Comment: For what it worth, denoting $\lambda \sin \theta=\sqrt{x}$ we get for $g(x)=f(\sqrt{x})$ the Volterra integral equation $\int_0^T g(x) (T-x)^{-1/2}dx=0$ for all $T>0$.

Comment: I tried that too and a couple of other changes of variables that get the $\lambda$ out of $f$. I got stuck all the same.

Comment: Equation which @Fedor Petrov wrote is a Laplace convolution, so if he Laplace transform of $g$ exists, it indeed must be 0.

Comment: This may he rephrased as $g*h=0$ where $h(x)=x^{-1/2}$ for $x>0$ and $h(x)=0$ otherwise. Unfortunately, we can not directly apply Fourier transform or Wiener Tauberian theorem, but this looks close.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko In the application where this came up I can't quite assume that $f$ is of exponential order, but that already gives something nice. Thanks!!

Comment: If $h(x) = \int_0^x g(s) (x-s)^{-1/2} ds = 0$, then, by Fubini, $0 = \int_0^x h(s) (x-s)^{-1/2} ds = \pi \int_0^x g(t) dt$, and hence $g = 0$ almost everywhere. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As suggested by Fedor Petrov, we write
$$ g(x) = f(\sqrt x) , $$
and we substitute $\lambda \sin\theta = \sqrt{x}$ and $t = \lambda^2$. This leads to
$$ \begin{aligned} 0 & = 2 \lambda \int_0^{\pi/2} f(\lambda \sin \theta) \sin \theta \, d\theta \\ & = \int_0^{\lambda^2} 2 f(\sqrt x) \sqrt{x} \, \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x (\lambda^2 - x)}} \, dx \\ & = \int_0^t \frac{g(x)}{\sqrt{t - x}} \, dx . \end{aligned} $$

Now, this is the "half-integral" of $g$: the convolution of $g$ with $x^{-1/2}$ is the fractional Riemann–Liouville integral of $g$, up to a constant factor. Adding another half-integral leads to the usual integral: by Fubini,
$$ \begin{aligned} 0 & = \int_0^s \biggl(\int_0^t \frac{g(x)}{\sqrt{t - x}} dx\biggr) \frac{1}{\sqrt{s - t}} dt \\ & = \int_0^s g(x) \biggl(\int_x^s \frac{1}{\sqrt{t - x}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{s - t}} dt \biggr) dx . \end{aligned} $$
The inner integral is just $\pi$: substituting $t = x + (s - x) u$, we obtain
$$ \int_x^s \frac{1}{\sqrt{t - x}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{s - t}} dt = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(s - x) \sqrt{u (1 - u)}} \, (s - x) \, du = \pi .$$
It follows that
$$ 0 = \pi \int_0^s g(x) dx , $$
which clearly implies that $g$ is zero almost everywhere. *Edit: ...and since $g$ is continuous, almost everywhere yields everywhere (as pointed out by Fedor Petrov in a comment below).*

Comment: ...and since $g$ is continuous, almost everywhere yields everywhere

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Right, of course. And so my contribution to this answer decreased to 1/3. :-)

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki, that's lovely !!

Comment: Let me see if I'm getting this from the conceptual viewpoint: forgetting some multiplicative constants, Fedor Petrov's change of variables makes the integral into the Riemann-Liouville integral $I^{1/2} g$, then you use the  $I^{1/2} I^{1/2} = I^1$ relation to show that the antiderivative of $g$ must be zero. Is that an accurate summary?

Comment: BTW, I think there is no $u$ in the numerator in the next to last integral.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea of the argument. And sorry for the typo.